# CSS: Not fixed text div Width

Tags: css, html, text, width, fixed

I'm working on a personal project and I'm having a design issue:

Say you have a div with this text: "Hello my name is Daniel..." and another div under that..

So the width should be the size that takes that phrase and element; not the size of the whole container.

This is my code in HTML:

```
<div id="feed">

        <div class="post">
            <div class="feed-msg">
                <p>My name is Daniel...</p>
                <div class="meta">5 hours ago.</div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- [End] .post -->
</div>
```

This is my code in CSS:

```
#feed {
 position: relative;
}

#feed .post {
min-height: 55px;
margin-left: 90px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#feed .post div.feed-msg {
padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/uhEBs/ ?

Use

```
#feed .post div.feed-msg {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Moreover, you can join `padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 15px` into `padding: 9px 15px 10px 15px`

Comment: You genius, Thank you! Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You placed your meta div within your msg div. You might get an easier time separating them and having the meta as part of the post div instead, then set up their respective width